# Problemas cargando tipografía en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Las fuentes las tengo en una carpeta llamada `fonts` dentro del theme, en el cual tengo cada una en `woff`, `woff2` y `otf`. La tipografía no se encuentra en GoogleFonts, así que hay que cargarla de manera manual.

He intentado varias cosas para que me cargue la tipografía, les escribo dichos intentos, todos fallidos:

CSS: solo woff y woff2

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Geomanist;
    font-weight:100;
    font-style:normal;
    src: url("./fonts/geomanist-light.woff") format('woff'),
        url("./fonts/geomanist-light.woff2") format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Geomanist;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style:normal;
    src: url("./fonts/geomanist-regular.woff") format('woff'),
        url("./fonts/geomanist-regular.woff2") format('woff2');
}
```

CSS: con otf

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Geomanist;
    font-weight:100;
    font-style:normal;
    src: local('Geomanist light'),
        url("./fonts/geomanist-light.woff") format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Geomanist;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style:normal;
    src: local('Geomanist regular'),
        url("./fonts/geomanist-regular.woff") format('opentype');
}
```

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_fonts' );
function add_fonts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'Geomanist light', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Geomanist-Light.otf' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Geomanist regular', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Geomanist-Regular.otf' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Geomanist book', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Geomanist-Book.otf' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Geomanist bold', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Geomanist-Bold.otf' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Geomanist black', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Geomanist-Black.otf' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'Geomanist ultra', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Geomanist-Ultra.otf' );
}
```

Comment: En el primer ejemplo tienes puesto _url_ en lugar de _local_. Supongo que la ruta desde el CSS es correcta ¿no? Que  la carpeta fonts está al mismo nivel que el archivo .css

Comment: Si, la carpeta y el archivo .css estan en el mismo nivel. Y si coloco la ruta que se genera y la pego en el navegador, me aparece para descargar la fuente. Pero por cónsola me dispara un montón de errores

Comment: Lo que te decía de _local_ ni caso, me he confundido, _url_ está bien. ¿Qué errores te da? Eso podría ayudar

Comment: Actualmente tengo el CSS como la primera opción que coloqué y me dispara este error: `downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Geomanist" style:normal weight:bold stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147746065 source: (mi URL)/wp-content/themes/(nombre del theme)/fonts/geomanist-black.woff2`
Y cuando las incluí por el archivo functions me decía que `wp_enqueue_style` recibe son archivos text/css y la fuente es un archivo de otro tipo

Comment: ¿Eso es en firefox? ¿En otros navegadores funciona? He visto ese error antes pero trabajando en local, en el servidor no ocurría.

Comment: Eso me muestra en Firefox, en Chrome me muestra `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62449/discussion-between-blonfu-and-marisabelgc).

Comment: El error 404 puede hacer pensar que hay un problema con la url de los archivos. ¿Has probado poniendo la url absoluta donde se encuentran los mismos. Es decir,  `src: url("http://tu-sitio/otras-subcarpetas/fonts/geomanist-light.woff")`en lugar de `src: url("./fonts/geomanist-light.woff")`

Answer (score 0):

Los errores que tenés en la consola seguramente son porque estás tratando de cargar los archivos de las fuentes con `wp_enqueue_style()`. Esa función se usa sólo para cargar una hoja de estilos en el `<head>` de tu tema.

Comentá esa porción de código en `functions.php` y en la hoja de estilos de tu tema pegá esto:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Geomanist';
    src: url('fonts/geomanist-light.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/geomanist-light.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/geomanist-light.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Geomanist';
    src: url('fonts/geomanist-regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/geomanist-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/geomanist-regular.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Con eso ya debería funcionar.

**Tip**: Para facilitarte esta tarea podés usar un [generador de webfonts](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator/). Con esta herramienta podés convertir a los formatos de fuente que necesitás para la web y también te da el CSS necesario para utilizarlas.